# Affine transformation of a gaussian vector

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

We know that (d is the dimension of the vector $X$):

$X$ has distribution $\mathcal{N}_{d}({\mu},{\Sigma})$

${Y=\Sigma^{-1/2}(X-\mu)=\Sigma^{-1/2}X-\Sigma^{-1/2}\mu}$

Since ${\Sigma}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix, we know that ${\Sigma^{-1}}$ is also symmetric positive definite. Moreover, ${\Sigma^{-1/2}}$ is the positive square root of ${\Sigma^{-1}}$, that is, the one satisfying ${\Sigma^{-1/2}\Sigma^{-1/2}=\Sigma^{-1}}$. We remark that  ${Y}$ defines an affine transformation of ${X}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ so we can use a well know result of affine transformation of a Gaussian vector :
\begin{equation*}
    {Y}\sim\mathcal{N}_{d}({\Sigma^{-1/2}\mu -\Sigma^{-1/2}\mu,\Sigma^{-1/2}\Sigma\Sigma^{-1/2} })
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        &{\Sigma^{-1/2}\mu -\Sigma^{-1/2}\mu}=0_{d}\\
        &{\Sigma^{-1/2}\Sigma\Sigma^{-1/2}}= ?\quad\quad\quad                (1)
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

and I'm getting trouble when it comes to compute $(1)$, I would like to use a commutative property but nothing allows me to do it in my knowledge

Edit : Roger answered the question !

Comment: you can use that $\Sigma = \Sigma^{1/2}  \Sigma^{1/2} $

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, a decomposition of $\Sigma$ is a good start for sure, but how can I be sure that $\Sigma^{1/2}\Sigma^{-1/2}=I_{d}$ ?  I mean I have an intuition on that using power results on real numbers but for matrices I lack knowledge..

Comment: Are you allowed to use that the identity is the only symmetric positive definite matrix that is equal to its square root?

Comment: $A^{1/2}=A\implies A=I_{d}$ for A a symmetric positive definite matrix ? I don't think so since I'm not able to see why this result is true..

Comment: It is true though: $A$ has real eigenvalues and is diagonalizable because it is symmetric. The positive definiteness implies that the eigenvalues are positive, so the eigenvalues must all be equal to one if $A^{1/2} = A$.

Comment: Thank you a lot I can follow your argument !! But I don't see how it helps me now ? Because I don't have that $\Sigma^{1/2}=\Sigma$ nor $\Sigma^{-1/2}=\Sigma^{-1}$ ?Thank you to take the time to help me to understand this.

Comment: Let $A = \Sigma^{-1/2} \Sigma \Sigma^{-1/2} $, $A$ is symmetric positive definite and such that $A^2 = A$.

Comment: Oh okay  I was not wortking wit the good matrix . Thank you a lot !!

Comment: you're welcome!